# 23/3 PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE' must be declared

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dbms-output

I am not sure how to resolve the above error I am getting. How should I declare it? I created the procedure below to allow a passenger to buy a metro card and add it to an existing account. Input includes account id, initial balance

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
-- procedure to buy new metro, output error if account already exists. 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NewCard (

input_Account_ID IN varchar,
input_Balance IN varchar,
input_age IN varchar

)

IS 
acct varchar(255);
-- compare the input account id to see if it exists in the table
CURSOR S1 is SELECT Account_id from Rider_Account where ACCOUNT_ID = input_Account_ID;

BEGIN
--THIS MEANS THE RECORD EXISTS
open S1;
LOOP
FETCH S1 into acct; 
EXIT WHEN S1%notfound; 
END LOOP;
-- go through the records

IF (acct = input_Account_ID) THEN

Dbms_ouput.Put_line('Account exists');

ELSE 
BEGIN 
  INSERT into Metro_Card(Card_ID, Account_ID, Balance) VALUES(Card_Sequence.NEXTVAL,input_Account_ID, input_Balance); 
  INSERT into rider_account(Age) VALUES (input_age);

   END;
   END IF;  

IF (input_age <= 12) THEN
  UPDATE Metro_Card
  SET Discount_type = 2
  Where Metro_Card.Account_ID = input_Account_ID; 
ELSIF (input_age >= 65) THEN
  UPDATE Metro_Card 
  SET Discount_type = 3
  Where Metro_Card.Account_ID = input_Account_ID;
ELSE 
  UPDATE Metro_Card 
  SET Discount_type = 1
  Where Metro_Card.Account_ID = input_Account_ID;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: nice question ,thnks for posting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not

```
Dbms_ouput.Put_line('Account exists');
```

but

```
Dbms_ouTput.Put_line('Account exists'); 
       -
       ^
       missing "T"
```